# .NET Serialization Problem with Referencing a Static Field

Tags: .net, serialization

I'm using `SerializableAttribute` to write an object `jack` to disk. The object has a member `department` which references a static field `accounts` of another class `Department`. On deserializing, I find that the member `department` of the deserialized object no longer points to the same object as the static field `accounts` but now points to another identical copy.

All classes and objects involved are reference types. How do I get around this?

(Sorry about long code post.)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Runtime::Serialization;
using namespace System::Runtime::Serialization::Formatters::Binary;

[Serializable]
ref class Department {
    static Department(){ accounts = gcnew Department(L"Accounts"); }
public:
    static Department ^accounts;
    // similarly other departments come here...

    String ^name;
    Department(String ^name) : name(name) { }
};

[Serializable]
ref class Employee {
public:
    String ^name;
    Department ^department;

    Employee(String ^name, Department ^department) : name(name),
        department(department) { }

};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Employee ^jack;
    IFormatter ^formatter = gcnew BinaryFormatter();

    String ^option = Console::ReadLine();
    if(option == L"read"){
        Stream ^stream = gcnew FileStream(L"dingdong.bin", FileMode::Open,
            FileAccess::Read, FileShare::Read);
        jack = (Employee^) formatter->Deserialize(stream);

        if(jack->department != Department::accounts)
            Console::WriteLine(L"Different objects");
        else
            Console::WriteLine(L"The same object");
        stream->Close();
        Console::ReadLine();
    }
    else {
        jack = gcnew Employee(L"Jack", Department::accounts);
        Stream ^stream = gcnew FileStream(L"dingdong.bin", FileMode::Create,
            FileAccess::Write, FileShare::None);
        formatter->Serialize(stream, jack);
        stream->Close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Added example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest case, `[NonSerialized]` with `IDeserializationCallback` to restore the reference will do the trick. You can serialize a department code instead. Generally, if you need to serialize such singleton-like objects, you can [serialize the referring object manually and substitute a «reference» object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301767.aspx), which implements `IObjectReference`, or, possibly, use [serialization surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx) instead of manual serialization to substitute the «reference» object.

PS: generally, I wouldn't recommend using default binary serialization for anything serious, because of various assembly-binding and versioning problems it tends to produce. In short, *serialization is difficult*, and cannot be simplified much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you do. When you serialize, a serialized copy of the current value of `f`'s static field. When this is deserialized, an object of the relevant type is created and its values hydrated from the serialized data. These may be reference types, but serialization is about transferring the values of objects between A and B, not their references.

You are saving to disk. How do you even know that `f` and its static field are still going to be in scope when you load from disk and deserialize?

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the [NonSerialized] attribute documentation, I think you'll find this example there.

---

Ok, now that you've posted the code, the problem becomes more clear. You should separate out the static part of the Department class into a `Departments` class. A list or enumeration of departments has nothing to do with the individual Department objects.